# RevClusterMap radius

Tags: ios, xcode, mapkit

I'm using REVClusterMap in my project to get my map annotations clustered on different levels of zoom so I don't show all of them at once as there are many. The problem is that on certain levels, some of the annotations get included in a cluster that's not very close. So I'm guessing this is because of the radius in which they get clustered. Is there any way to do this? The BASE_RADIUS doesn't seem to be used anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, it seems that it doesn't work using the BASE_RADIUS after all. It splits the view in several areas and then clusters the ones that get in the respective area.